# Power supply unit for Intel server motherboard S1200v3RPS with Xeon E3 processor. 5-pin aux power cable missing

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, xeon

I am trying to put a server together to install Ubuntu. I bought an Intel S1200v3RPS motherboard and plugged an Intel Xeon E3 processor into it. I purchased a 1U chassis from Supermicro with a power supply.

The power supply does not have a 5-pin cable to the motherboard's Auxiliary Power Supply socket. A bit of research did not give any definite answer on the need for the 5-pin connection. The motherboard does not power on and the CPU fan is off. I tested the power supply on a desktop Intel motherboard and it works fine.

I would like to buy a new power supply but could not find one which expressly stated that it comes with the 5-pin aux power supply cable. Any recommendations on a power supply unit for this motherboard would be helpful. Any comments on the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 5 pin? They're more typically 4 or 8 pin, and I see a 8 pin connector, not a 5 pin connector when I googled the board.

Comment: It is 5 pin all right. It is labeled in the installation document as Auxiliary Power Supply. On the motherboard itself, it is labeled as PS Aux. It is in the same line as the main power connector and close to the CPU power connector.  I am really stumped because there is no discussion in any forum on this issue.  Supermicro support team simply brushed the issue aside saying that they do not deal with Intel motherboards!

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/71385/Intel-Server-Board-S1200V3RPS#@productimages not seeing a 5 pin connector. I see a standard 8 pin next to the ram

Comment: Please look at step 8 of the following instructions:  http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/522970_g83551_002_s1200rp_qsug.pdf

Comment: @Samir - You need to follow the Supermicro instructions not the Intel instructions.  "If you are using a
non-Intel® server
chassis with an ATX
power supply, see
the documentation
that came with your
chassis for installation
information."

Comment: The motherboard is Intel, the server chassis came without the motherboard but only the Power supply. I ordered it that way. Yes, there are issues with some of the control panel cables (reset, HDD LEd, NIC LED, etc.) but there are adapter cables to work around.

Comment: Tried another power supply from Corsair and the motherboard powered up even though there is no Aux. Power supply cable.  I got stuck with another problem though... Posted a fresh question on that... I got POST code error of 00101011 for which there is no explanation in the Intel motherboard manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PSAUX connector on Intel server boards is used when interfacing with a compatible 'intelligent' redundant power supply system.  It should also be usable with non-redundant supplies, but I've never seen it implemented (even with Intel's own chassis/PSUs).

The connector is an [I2C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) signaling line so the motherboard's system management bus (SMBUS) can communicate the power supplies, so it can monitor their status (fan speeds, temperatures, voltages, failure of one PSU in a redundant set, etc.) and report it back to the OS.

Its use is not required for operation of the motherboard.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

The Supermicro PWS-865-PQ is an 80 Plus level power supply capable of continuously supplying 865W output power at 85% efficiency. Enjoy the simplicity of active power factor correction (PFC) and automatically correct AC input for a full range of voltages and a quiet fan to keep it cool under heavy loads. This power supply is designed to not only provide you reliable power to your desktop or workstation but also protects it from over voltage, over current and short circuiting via protective circuitry embedded into the unit. All materials contained comply with RoHS requirements and is certified by Supermicro.

Cables Included:
1x 24 Pin ATX (Motherboard)
2x 8 Pin 12V (CPU)
1x 4 Pin 12V (CPU)
2x 6 Pin PCI-E
2x (6+2) 8 Pin PCI-E
6x 4 Pin Legacy HDD
2x 4 Pin Floppy/DVD Drive
2x SATA Power Connectors
1x SMBus

Comment: This sounds like an advertisement.   If you are quoting from the manufacturer’s promotional material, you must say so.  If you are affiliated/associated with the manufacturer, you must say so.