# Power connectors for intel S5520UR motherboard confusion

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I'm looking into using the Intel S5520UR motherboard for a hobby computer project. On the manual, it says it uses three power cables: a 24-pin connector, an 8-pin connector, and a 5-pin connector. The pinouts for the 24- and 8-pin seem standard, so I'm not worried about them. I've never seen a five-pin connector, however.

It mentions this about its purpose, but I don't know what it means:

> One SSI-compliant 1x5 pin connector (J1K2), which provides I^2C
>   monitoring of the power supply.

More specifics about the exact specifications:

> 3.7.3 P3 – Power Signal Connector
>
> Connector housing: 5-pin Molex* 50-57-9705 or equivalent
>
> Contact: Molex 16-02-0087 or equivalent

Pinout:

[image: pinout]

(Pinout from page 93 of [the manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/s5520ur/sb/e44031012_s5520ur_s5520urt_tps_r1_9.pdf))

My questions:

1. What is this connector for? Is it normally found on PSUs?
2. Do I need this connector? (I.e., will a standard PSU with only a 24-pin and 8-pin molex connector be able to power this motherboard?)
3. What does "I^2C monitoring of the power supply" mean?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/900400/power-supply-unit-for-intel-server-motherboard-s1200v3rps-with-xeon-e3-processor seems related, if not a dupe... That does look like a way for a server PSU to communicate with a motherboard, rather than a full/proper power connector. I2C is a low speed data channel of some flavour

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Wow, I completely missed that. I'll flag this as a dupe.

Comment: Amusingly, I found it googling your problem  - I just googled" power signal connector server" and looked around. Its hardly obvious to be honest,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this connector for? Is it normally found on PSUs?

As it says, monitoring of the power supply.

> Do I need this connector? (I.e., will a standard PSU with only a 24-pin and 8-pin molex connector be able to power this motherboard?)

Yes, but you can't monitor the power supply.

> What does "I^2C monitoring of the power supply" mean?

I^2C is a protocol for serial communication. It's used to monitor the power supply's input and output voltages and power levels. It's almost certainly optional.

Comment: Thanks, the "almost certainly optional" is what I need to know. From the question Journeyman Geek shared, it seems to be a very rarely-implemented connector.